# Where can I find this Besht quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, hasidic-story, baal-shem-tov

In Elie Wiesel's book Gates of the Forest he relates a story about the Baal Shem Tov the ends with the words: "G-d made man because he loves stories". Can anyone please help me with locating the Chassidic sefer which is the source of this?

Comment: Seems to be a take on זֶה סֵפֶר תּוֹלְדֹת אָדָם.

Comment: Wiesel heard a lot of stories growing up in a chassidic environment. This one sounds very folksy, so I doubt it is in a proper book.

Comment: I searched the otzar hachochma database and all I found was that Hashem likes stories of tzaddikim, not that he created man because of it...